# Traefik 1.7 upgrade breaks kubernetes 1.7.12

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

We have been traefik for over a year and it has been great. We are currently on 1.6.6 and everything works as expected, once we try to upgrade to 1.7 all of our endpoints get 502s. Any idea why this could be happening?

We are trying to upgrade because NS1 was introduced as a DNS provider and it seems like HTTP challenges no longer work.

This our current setup:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  traefik.toml: |
    # traefik.toml
    defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
    [web]
    address = ":8080"

    [entryPoints]
      [entryPoints.http]
        address = ":80"
        [entryPoints.http.redirect]
          entryPoint = "https"

      [entryPoints.https]
      address = ":443"
       [entryPoints.https.redirect]
         [entryPoints.https.tls]

    [kubernetes]
    [acme]
    email = "devops@something.com"
    storage = "/acme/acme.json"
    entryPoint = "https"
    acmeLogging = true
    caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    [[acme.domains]]
      main = "something.com"
    [[acme.domains]]
      main = "something.com"
    [acme.httpChallenge]
      entryPoint = "http"
    [retry]
    attempts = 5
    [accessLog]
    [traefikLog]
    filePath = "/acme/traefik.log"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app: traefik
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: traefik
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector: 
        role: edge-routers
      containers:
      - args:
        - --configfile=/config/traefik.toml
        - --kubernetes
        - --api
        - -d
        image: traefik:1.6.6 
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
        name: traefik
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /config
          name: config
        - mountPath: /acme
          name: acme
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: traefik
        name: config
      - hostPath:
          path: /etc/traefik
        name: acme
```

Seems like we are getting:

> time="2019-02-08T00:40:58Z" level=debug msg="'502 Bad Gateway' caused by: EOF"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like traefik increased their time between bytes and our internal cache was timing out due to it. Fixed by increasing the timeout.